# discord.py only registering some of my hybrid commands

Tags: python, discord.py

I am making a discord bot in python with discord.py and I am using commands.hybrid_commands to register slash commands as well as normal commands but The bot is only registering slash commands in the cogs that have 2 commands inside of them for example my information cog only has the test command and the ping command and it is reading it fine but my moderation cog has 5 different commands in it and is not registering any of them.

**This is the main.py file**

```
import discord
import asyncio
import re
from discord.ext import commands
import os

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = "!", intents = discord.Intents.all())
#client.remove_command("help")



@client.event
async def on_ready():
    await client.change_presence(activity=discord.Activity(type=discord.ActivityType.watching, name="a movie"))
    print('Logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))    # Lets you know when the bot is online
    try:
        synced = await client.tree.sync()
        print(f"Synced {len(synced)} command(s)")
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)

@client.command(name='load', description='Loads the given cog')
async def load(ctx, extension):
    await client.load_extension(f"cogs.{extension}")
    await ctx.send(f"Loaded {extension}.")
    print(f"Loaded {extension}.py")

@client.command(name='unload', description='Unloads the given cog')
async def unload(ctx, extension):
    await client.unload_extension(f"cogs.{extension}")
    await ctx.send(f"Unloaded {extension}.")
    print(f"Unloaded {extension}.py")

@client.command(name='reload', description='Re-loads the given cog')
async def reload(ctx, extension):
    await client.reload_extension(f"cogs.{extension}")
    await ctx.send(f"Re-loaded {extension}.")
    print(f"Re-loaded {extension}.py")

async def load_extensions():
    for filename in os.listdir("./cogs"):
        if filename.endswith(".py"):
            await client.load_extension(f"cogs.{filename[:-3]}")

async def main():
    async with client:
        await load_extensions()
        await client.start("TOKEN")

asyncio.run(main())
```

**This is my information.py cog**

```
class Information(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client
    
    # Test command
    @commands.hybrid_command(name='test', description='Just a basic test command to see if the commands are working.')
    async def test(self, ctx):
        await ctx.send("Everything is working fine!")

    # Latency command
    @commands.hybrid_command(name='ping', description='Sends the bots letency/response time in ms.')
    async def ping(self, ctx):
        await ctx.send(f"Pong {round(self.client.latency * 1000)}ms")

async def setup(client):
    await client.add_cog(Information(client))
```

**And this is my moderation.py cog**

```
class Moderation(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client

        @commands.hybrid_command(name='purge', description='Purges the given amount of messages from the channel.')
        @commands.has_permissions(manage_messages=True)
        async def purge(self, ctx, amount: int):
            await ctx.channel.purge(limit=amount)
            await ctx.send(f"Successfully cleared {amount} messages!")

        @commands.hybrid_command(name='kick', description='Kicks the mentioned user from the guild.')
        @commands.has_permissions(kick_members=True)
        async def kick(self, ctx, member: discord.Member, *, reason=None):
            await discord.Member.kick(member)
            await ctx.send(f"{member} has been kicked.")

        @commands.hybrid_command(name='mute', description='Mutes the mentioned user for the given amount of time.')
        @commands.has_permissions(manage_roles=True)
        async def mute(self, ctx, member:discord.Member, *, time:TimeConverter = None, reason=None):
            """Mutes a member for the specified time- time in 2d 10h 3m 2s format ex:
            &mute @Someone 1d"""
            role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name="Muted")
            memRole = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name='Member')
            await member.remove_roles(memRole)
            await member.add_roles(role)
            await ctx.send(("Muted {} for {}s" if time else "Muted {}").format(member, time))
            if time:
                await asyncio.sleep(time)
                await member.add_roles(memRole)
                await member.remove_roles(role)

        @commands.hybrid_command(name='unmute', description='Unmutes the mentioned user.')
        @commands.has_permissions(manage_roles=True)
        async def unmute(self, ctx, member:discord.Member, *, reason=None):
            role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name="Muted")
            memRole = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name='Member')
            await member.remove_roles(role)
            await member.add_roles(memRole)
            await ctx.send(f'Unmuted {member}.')

async def setup(client):
    await client.add_cog(Moderation(client))
```

Comment: So you want it to both react to `/Test` and `!Test`?

Comment: Yeah I want it to react to both

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To register both a slash command and a message command at the same time, you can use `hybrid_command`s.

For example:

```py
@commands.hybrid_command()
async def test(self, ctx):
    await ctx.send("Everything is working fine!")
```

Docs: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=hybrid_command#discord.ext.commands.hybrid_command

Comment: oh, thank you! I didn't realize that was a thing hahaha

Comment: Now that I have added that into the cogs for each command it's only registering 4 commands.

Comment: This is an edit to my above comment

The bot is only registering slash commands in the cogs that have 2 commands inside of them for example my information cog only has the test command and the ping command and it is reading it fine but my moderation cog has 5 different commands in it and is not registering any of them.

Comment: @SwiftAU Hmm, hard to tell what's wrong without seeing it. Could you edit your post with the current code?

Comment: Done! I just edited the post with the updated code.

Comment: @SwiftAU Your indentation is wrong, you need to indent your commands one less. As it is right now, they are all in your `__init__` function.

Comment: Oh haha I am so dumb I fixed an issue with that yesterday, let me try it and ill reply to let you know